# Sending two different object types to a JMS queue listener

Tags: java, spring-jms

I build an application which is using Spring JMS.

I have two producer methods which queue messages to the same destination (`TX_REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME`).

Each one of them is queueing a different type of object (don't notice on the return value, that's not the issue).

1st method: `sendDbTransactions` is queueing a new `DbTransactionDto` object:

```
public String sendDbTransactions(DbTransactionRequestDto request) {
    logger.info("Queueing DB transaction message.")
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(TX_REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME, new DbTransactionDto(request))
    return null
}
```

2nd method: `sendCrTransactions` is queueing a new `CrTransactionDto` object:

```
public String sendCrTransactions(CrTransactionRequestDto request) {
    logger.info("Queueing CR transaction message.")
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(TX_REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME, new CrTransactionDto(request))
    return null
}
```

What I want to achieve is that in my consumer method be capable of receive these two types of objects (I don't know how to do it, maybe unmarshall them) and recover either `DbTransactionDto` object or `CrTransactionDto` object.

What I have achieved so far in my consumer method, is to receive an `ActiveMQTextMessage` object, getting its `properties` property using `getProperties()` function (which returns a `Map<String,Object>`) and then getting the `_type` key in the Map who has a `String` value like `com.jms.model.dto.DBTransactionDto`. This way I know which object is being sended through the queue with the `contains` function analysed in the `IF` statement.

Then with the `getBody()` function "parse" (or I suppose "unmarshall", I don't know) its content to recover whichever of my two objects:

```
@JmsListener(destination = TX_REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME, containerFactory = JMS_CONTAINER_FACTORY_NAME)
public void consumeMessage(ActiveMQTextMessage receivedMessage) {
    try {
        String typeProperty = (String) receivedMessage.getProperties().get("_type");
        if(typeProperty.contains("DBTransactionDto")) {
            DBTransactionDto dbTransactionDto = (DbTransactionDto) receivedMessage.getBody(DBTransactionDto.class);
            logger.info("===> Received DB request message: " + dbTransactionDto.toString());
        } else if(typeProperty.contains("CRTransactionDto")) {
            CRTransactionDto crTransactionDto = (CrTransactionDto) receivedMessage.getBody(CRTransactionDto.class);
            logger.info("===> Received CR request message: " + crTransactionDto.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("EXCEPTION: Error receiving message. ", ex);
    }
}
```

But when either `getBody()` line is excecuted, throws the following error:

> WARN 2021-07-21 04:01:21.951 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer:929] - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage.getBody(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

For reference, this is my message converter `Bean` that I am using. It is using `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` that is provided by Spring JMS:

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}
```

Is there a way or a function in Spring JMS to "unmarshall"an ActiveMQTextMessage message to its internal defined object type?

 Or do I have to use message type ObjectMessage in my queue?

Many thanks in advance!